# One API call to retrieve all items in the model

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a simple web api using Net Core 2.2.  I have this api controller below, that gets one particular dungeon.

It is returning a dungeon as JSON, but it's not returning the MonsterList associated with the dungeon.

So this is my controller:

```
    // GET: api/DungeonLists/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<DungeonList>> GetDungeonList(Guid id)
    {
        var dungeonList = await _context.DungeonList.FindAsync(id);

        if (dungeonList == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return dungeonList;
    }
```

And here is my model for the Dungeon.  As you can see, it has a MonsterList.

```
    public partial class DungeonList
{
    public DungeonList()
    {
        MonsterList = new HashSet<MonsterList>();
    }

    public Guid DungeonId { get; set; }
    public string DungeonName { get; set; }
    public string DungeonDesc { get; set; }
    public string MapArea { get; set; }
    public bool ShowProgress { get; set; }
    public bool? DungeonResumable { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MonsterList> MonsterList { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my MonsterList model:

```
    public partial class MonsterList
{
    public string MonsterId { get; set; }
    public Guid DungeonId { get; set; }
    public string MonsterName { get; set; }
    public byte? MonsterType { get; set; }
    public bool IsBossMonster { get; set; }

    public virtual DungeonList Dungeon { get; set; }
}
```

I want the JSON to also show the list of monsters associated with the dungeon.

Is there a way to do this?  Or would I need to make a separate API call?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. If you want to *include* `MonterList` in the result, then just [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) it.

Comment: @IvanStoev I mistakenly thought that having MonsterList in the class model of DungeonList would mean that it would be populated as well.  Like every Monster with the same DungeonId would be included

Comment: Well, that's a common mistake with EF Core - it *doesn't* include (load) the related data if not specifically asked to do that. Reading  the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) documentation topic is a must :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code to the following:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<DungeonList>> GetDungeonList(Guid id)
{
    var dungeonList = await _context.DungeonList
                                    .Include(i => i.MonsterList)
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id = id);

    if (dungeonList == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return dungeonList;
}
```

Additionally, since you arent using LazyLoading, you dont need the [virtual] on the MonsterList collection